# Why are convolutions still used in some Transformer networks for speech enhancement?

Tags: machine-learning, transformer, attention-mechanism

So I’ve read in [Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762v5.pdf) that Transformers remove the need for recurrence and convolutions entirely. However, I’ve seen some TNNs (such as [SepFormer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.13154.pdf), [DPTNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.13975.pdf), and [TSTNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.09963v1.pdf)) that still utilize convolutions. Is there any particular reason for this? Doesn’t that defeat the purpose of Transformers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We find some justifications in the [Conformer paper](http://www.interspeech2020.org/uploadfile/pdf/Thu-3-10-9.pdf):

- Convolutions are better than Transformers at detecting fine-grained patterns:

  > While Transformers are good at modeling long-range global context, they are less capable to extract fine-grained local feature patterns. Convolution neural networks (CNNs), on the other hand, exploit local information and are
  > used as the de-facto computational block in vision.
- Together, they Transformers and convolutions work better than separately:

  > Recent works have shown that combining convolution and self-attention improves over using them individually [14]. Together, they are able to learn both position-wise local features, and use content-based global interactions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I haven’t come across this paper. Will definitely read it.